# How do symlinks in a host volume work in Docker containers?

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

My question is about what happens when you create a symlink from inside a container in a host mounted directory. It's easiest if I just ask with an example.

Assume we start a container like so. Most of the command doesn't matter, what's important here is the host volume mount.

```
docker run --rm -ti -h thecontainer -v /home/userguy:/container-home alpine /bin/sh
```

While in the container I create a symlink in the host volume directory

```
thecontainer$ ln -s /tmp /container-home/tmp-link
```

While in the container I can `ls /container-home/tmp-link` and I see the contents of the container's `/tmp` as expected.

Now, if I go back over to my host machine, I see the link `/home/userguy/tmp-link -> /tmp`. If I `ls` that directory I see the contents of the *host's* `/tmp`. i.e. Different results.

My question is, how do host volumes work under the covers that allow this situation to work? Is this a product of Docker or lxc itself? I was surprised to see this work because thought symlinks pointed to inodes and assumed /tmp in the container would be different from /tmp on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the virtual filesystem layer of the OS. A symlink contains a name, and the VFS resolves that name dynamically when the symlink is accessed.

Pointers to inodes are called **links**, usually called "hardlinks" to differentiate them from symlinks.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if the soft link also referenced the inode. So symlinks just contain a path and that path is resolved at read time. Thus the behavior I'm seeing is just a function of how symlinks work?